# How do I set tab pager indicator with solid color

Tags: android, tabs, viewpagerindicator, indicator

I spent too much time looking for a solution that make my app's header full of solid color. This similar to the new design of Google Play app. As you can see the below screenshot, the header is absolutely green.

expect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwt09.jpg

my implement: https://i.stack.imgur.com/30zXg.jpg

I looked at some libraries to implement this kind of tab indicator. But it's seem not what I'm looking for. There are a tiny divider between action bar and tab indicator. It should not to be here. This problem makes me upset all the time.

How should I do?

Comment: Use this to [generate custom actionbar styles](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

Comment: Nice online tool that will helps me so much. Thank for your share!

Answer (score 0):

To remove that shadow below the action bar, in your styles.xml you need to add the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item> //This line will remove that shadow
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, I find out my problem. I need to add above property to all the style.xml files. Now it works.